# Express, Mongodb (mongoose) - Data comparison and count

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

In my mongodb database i have datas like:

```
{ id: 'ran1', code: 'ABC1', createdAt: 'Sep 1 2022', count: 5 } 
{ id: 'ran2', code: 'ABC1', createdAt: 'Sep 2 2022', count: 3 } 
{ id: 'ran3', code: 'ABC2', createdAt: 'Sep 1 2022', count: 2 } 
{ id: 'ran4', code: 'ABC1', createdAt: 'Oct 1 2022', count: 1 } 
{ id: 'ran5', code: 'ABC1', createdAt: 'Oct 2 2022', count: 2 } 
{ id: 'ran6', code: 'ABC2', createdAt: 'Ocr 1 2022', count: 1 }
```

now as an output i want all the data from October but i also want to count and compare the percentage.
So the output for October will be

```
{code: 'ABC1', totalCount: the sum of total count of oct (1+2) =3 , percent: (total count of oct - total count of sep)/total count of oct * 100 } 
{code: 'ABC2', totalCount: 1, percent: -100}
```

I tried to achieve these output using two different aggregation and later map the current month aggregation with each element from previous month aggregation. But i think there are some better solution.

Here is my code

```
      const { filterDate, shop } = req.query;
      const splittedFilter = filterDate.split("-");

      const query = {
        shopUrl: { $regex: shop, $options: "i" },
        createdAt: {
          $gte: new Date(splittedFilter[0]),
          $lte: new Date(splittedFilter[1]),
        },
      };

      const currentCodes = await BlockedCode.aggregate([
        {
          $match: query,
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$discountCode",
            totalCount: { $sum: "$count" },
          },
        },
      ]);
      const prevQuery = {
        shopUrl: { $regex: shop, $options: "i" },
        createdAt: {
          $gte: new Date(splittedFilter[2]),
          $lte: new Date(splittedFilter[3]),
        },
      };
      const previousCodes = await BlockedCode.aggregate([
        {
          $match: prevQuery,
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$discountCode",
            totalCount: { $sum: "$count" },
          },
        },
      ]);

      const result = currentCodes.map((code) => {
        const foundPrevCode = previousCodes.find((i) => i._id === code._id);

        if (foundPrevCode?._id) {
          const prevCount = foundPrevCode?.totalCount;
          const currCount = code?.totalCount;
          const difference = currCount - prevCount;
          const percentage = (difference / currCount) * 100;
          return { ...code, percentage };
        } else {
          return { ...code, percentage: 100 };
        }
      });
```

Comment: `ABC1` is present two times in October, why does the total count show 3?

Answer (score 0):

@shahamar Rahman i don't understand percentage logic can you explain little more!

upto this i filtered and counted the data based October month,plz check it and let me know if it's helps you

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fet3UUI9LDC

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      month: {
        $month: {
          $toDate: "$createdAt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      month: 10
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        code: "$code"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: percent =  (total count of oct - total count of sep)/total count of oct * 100